# How do I use map to generalize a function

Tags: haskell

I am trying to design a Haskell program to build a game theory tree that creates a Game (capital G) by repeatedly playing a base game (small G) a specified number of times.

The *foo* function below works correctly by adding the outcome (or payoff) of one round to each of the outcomes/payoffs of the base game. One major limitation is that the base game is permanently set to have three outcomes.

The *foo'*  function (which does not work) is supposed to be a generalization of the *foo* function. That is to mimic the *foo* function by using the map function and a list of values that represent the base game.

```
data MyTree a = Root a [MyTree a] | Branch a [MyTree a] | Leaf a | EmptyNode deriving Show

x1:: Integer
x1 = 1

x2 :: Integer
x2 = 25

x3 :: Integer
x3 = 100

foo :: [Integer] -> MyTree [Integer] 
foo [r, a] 
    | r == 0      = Leaf   [a] 
    | a == 0      = Root   [a] [foo [r-1, a+x1], foo [r-1, a+x2], foo [r-1, a+x3]]
    | otherwise   = Branch [a] [foo [r-1, a+x1], foo [r-1, a+x2], foo [r-1, a+x3]]

lst = [x1, x2, x3]

foo' :: [Integer] -> MyTree [Integer] 
foo' [r, a] 
    | r == 0      = Leaf   [a] 
    | a == 0      = Root   [a] map (foo'.(\y ->[r-1, y]).(\x -> a+x)) lst
    | otherwise   = Branch [a] map (foo'.(\y ->[r-1, y]).(\x -> a+x)) lst
```

The following errors show up twice (one for the *a* *==* *0* line and for the *otherwise* line). I list them only once since once I know how to fix an error, I can fix its duplicate.

The error messages I get are (a) and (b):

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘([Integer] -> MyTree [Integer]) -> [[Integer]] -> MyTree [Integer]’with actual type ‘MyTree [Integer]’


Couldn't match expected type ‘[MyTree [Integer]]’with actual type ‘(a0 -> b0) -> [a0] -> [b0]’
```

My question is this: How can I get the actual input to match the expected input? I've spent many days and hours working on the syntax and Google-searching for the solution.

Comment: Unrelated: does `foo` always take exactly two arguments? If so, why are you making it take an arbitrary list instead of two arguments? In that way, `foo` becomes a partial function, which will crash your program if the list is of any other length. Worse, the compile won't check the list length at compile time.

Comment: The foo function was written knowing I would use a 3-outcome base game so I knew that x1, x2, and x3 would be enough. The generalization comes by allowing a base game with an arbitrary number of outcomes. This is why foo' uses the map function and lst.

Comment: I don't follow. Why isn't `foo :: Integer -> Integer -> MyTree ....` instead? Or `foo :: (Integer,Integer) -> MyTree ...`? In this way, the program will crash when called as `foo []` or `foo [1]` or `foo [1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is just what the compiler says:

> The function ‘Root’ is applied to four arguments,
>         but its type ‘[Integer] -> [MyTree [Integer]] -> MyTree [Integer]’
>         has only two

That's because compiler assumes that `[a]`, `map`, `(foo'.(\y ->[r-1, y]).(\x -> a+x))` and `lst` are four separate arguments to function `Root`.

It can be fixed either by using `$`, which sets the priority of evaluation

```
foo' :: [Integer] -> MyTree [Integer] 
foo' [r, a] 
    | r == 0      = Leaf   [a] 
    | a == 0      = Root   [a] $ map (foo'.(\y ->[r-1, y]).(\x -> a+x)) lst
    | otherwise   = Branch [a] $ map (foo'.(\y ->[r-1, y]).(\x -> a+x)) lst
```

Or, since it can be moved into a separate function (probably `genList` name is not appropriate, certainly you can make up a better one):

```
foo' :: [Integer] -> MyTree [Integer]
foo' [r, a]
    | r == 0      = Leaf   [a]
    | a == 0      = Root   [a] genList
    | otherwise   = Branch [a] genList
    where genList = map (foo'.(\y ->[r-1, y]).(\x -> a+x)) lst
```